# Would null value change the average?

Tags: sql, oracle, null, average

What will be the result of this query? (Oracle SQL)

```
   SELECT TO_CHAR(AVG(TEST_SCORE),'999,999.99') FROM SCORES;
```

If the values of TEST_SCORE are (96, 84, null)

isn't 90.00? Because null wouldn't change the answer?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `NULL` value will not change the average.  The average of the two numbers is 90.  In general, aggregation functions ignore `NULL` values -- including `min()`, `max()`, `avg()`, `count()` (except `count(*)`), and `sum()`.

[Here](http://rextester.com/DITM89998) is a little rextester showing what happens.

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try

```
with SCORES as (
  select 96 test_score from dual
  union all
  select 84 from dual
  union all
  select null from dual
)
SELECT TO_CHAR(AVG(TEST_SCORE),'999,999.99') FROM SCORES;
```